# How Disable Authentication on Infra Solr and Spark2 with a Kerberized Cluster

Tags: solr, kerberos, ambari

Hey guys I need to know how we can disable kerberos authentication on ambari for solr & spark2 web consoles.

I'm getting the Error 401 - Unauthorized access.

I just want to get in the web consoles with no need for authentication.

I don't need Spnego too.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Best Regards,
André Santos

Answer (score 0):

@Bedjase, This is just a hack.  You can look (in ambari) at what was changed for each component, and their dependencies, then try to remove those configuration changes created by kerberizing the cluster.  You may find its more than just those Solr and Spark.  If you just change those two, it could break stuff in the cluster (zookeeper, Ambari-metrics, and more).   This kind of change is also going to make the cluster not something that is supportable for future upgrades.